# Tracking function calls

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I would like to log function calls made during the execution of a C program.  The idea is to create a function call history.  I want this so I can programmatically verify that test fake functions were called.  I don't care about the arguments or return values.  Ideally I'd like it to look something like this:

```
long longfunc0();
void voidfunc2(char arg0, char arg1);

typedef void (*varargs_funcptr)(...);
void test1()
{
    varargs_funcptr function_calls[10];
    function_calls[0] = longfunc0;
    function_calls[1] = voidfunc2;
    assert(function_calls[0] == longfunc0);
}
```

Is it possible to make a typedef so that I don't need to explicitly cast to varargs_funcptr?

Comment: assert(function_calls[0] = longfunc0); <- you got it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [bta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79566/bta) for pointing me in the right direction.  Instead of using integers I use void pointers, but the solution is essentially the same.  The only thing I don't like about this solution is having to explicitly cast.

```
void test1()
{
    void * function_calls[10];
    function_calls[0] = (void *)longfunc0;
    function_calls[0] = (void *)voidfunc2;
    assert(function_calls[0] == ((void *)voidfunc2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only logging which functions ran and you won't be using these pointers later, it might be easier to cast the function pointer to an unsigned integer (of the appropriate length for your architecture).  You can still 'printf' out all of the pointers at the end of the program as hex addresses, and it won't matter what the argument type or quantity is.

The problem here is that your functions may not be located at the exact same memory addresses every time the program is run.  This makes it harder to figure out which function goes with which pointer.  It will require more memory, but you may have better luck storing a string representation of the function name.

Comment: This is interesting.  It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but if I was to store a string representation and address for the expected function call and just compare/assert on the addresses it could work.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you are trying to complicate your life

if you just try to do some small project add some logging function:

```
#if defined(LOGGING)
#define LOG(s) log(s)
#else
#define LOG(s)
#endif

void log(char *s){
    printf("%s");
    return;
}

void test1()
{
    log("test1()\n");

    return;
}
```

not sure if it works or doesn't have small errors, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to log in C is to use the functions defined in syslog.h (if you are in a Unix System) :

> ```
>  void closelog(void);
>
>  void openlog(const char *ident, int logopt, int facility);
>
>  int setlogmask(int maskpri);
>
>  void syslog(int priority, const char *message, ...);
>
>  void vsyslog(int priority, const char *message, va_list args);
> ```

When you use those functions, it directly writes your log to the system message logger (/var/log/myapplication.log for example).

This file also defines many log levels :

> LOG_EMERG       A panic condition. This is normally broadcast to all users.
>
> LOG_ALERT       A condition that should be corrected immediately, such as a corrupted system database.
>
> LOG_CRIT         Critical conditions, e.g., hard device errors.
>
> LOG_ERR          Errors.
>
> LOG_WARNING      Warning messages.
>
> LOG_NOTICE       Conditions that are not error conditions, but should possibly be handled specially.
>
> LOG_INFO         Informational messages.
>
> LOG_DEBUG        Messages that contain information normally of use only when debugging a program.

For instance, if you want to log using syslog, you can try this :

> /*  The second parameter means that
> the connection to syslog will open
> immediatly and you will print the id
> of process.
> */
>
> openlog("syslogd", LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID , LOG_SYSLOG);
>
> syslog(LOG_INFO, "Some blalblabla string");
>
> closelog();